# Authentication Unsuccessful with Mailkit C#

Tags: c#, email, office365, .net-6.0, mailkit

I am trying to use mailkit SDK for C# to send an email for a console app that will run on a schedule. Can confirm that there is no OTP or 2FA configured. Running into the following error message with the following code:

> 535: 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user credentials were incorrect. [BN8PR12CA0010.namprd12.prod.outlook.com 2023-04-27T20:31:00.281Z 08DB46E9CDA92BA3]

```
//c# code
using(var client = new SmtpClient())
{
    client.Connect(config.Email.Smtp, 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
    client.Authenticate(config.Email.Username, config.Email.Password);
    var message = new MimeMessage();
    message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("No-Reply", config.Email.From));
    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Display To User", config.Email.To));
    message.Subject = "Subject Goes Here";
    message.Body = new TextPart("html")
    {
        Text = errors.Any() ? string.Join("<br/>", errors) : "Ran to completion with no errors."
    };
    client.Send(message);
    client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

Stepped through the code and confirm that the exception is thrown on `client.Authenticate(...)`. Don't think its we are using an incorrect username and password since we are using the exact same thing within another powershell script.

```
//powershell 
$SMTPserver= "smtp.office365.com"
$username=no-reply@emaildomain.com
$password = "Password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username, $password)
Send-MailMessage -ErrorAction Stop -from $EmailFrom -to $EmailTo -cc $ccRecipients -subject $EmailSubject -body $EmailReport -SmtpServer $SMTPserver -Priority  Normal -Credential $credential -Port 587 -UseSsl
```

**Edit**

Added powershell send-mail cmdlet.
We are only using Ascii characters within username and password. Pretty confident its also not a simple typo issue as my other teammates are running into the same issue - including the person who set the password.

We are using Mailkit version 4.0.

Below is the protocol log.

```
Connected to smtp://smtp.office365.com:587/?starttls=when-available
S: 220 BN8PR04CA0063.outlook.office365.com Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 1 May 2023 12:41:38 +0000
C: EHLO BLD
S: 250-BN8PR04CA0063.outlook.office365.com Hello [161.199.135.241]
S: 250-SIZE 157286400
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-DSN
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-STARTTLS
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-BINARYMIME
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250 SMTPUTF8
C: STARTTLS
S: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
C: EHLO BLD
S: 250-BN8PR04CA0063.outlook.office365.com Hello [161.199.135.241]
S: 250-SIZE 157286400
S: 250-PIPELINING
S: 250-DSN
S: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
S: 250-AUTH LOGIN XOAUTH2
S: 250-8BITMIME
S: 250-BINARYMIME
S: 250-CHUNKING
S: 250 SMTPUTF8
C: AUTH LOGIN
S: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
C: ********
S: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
C: ********
S: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, the user credentials were incorrect. [BN8PR04CA0063.namprd04.prod.outlook.com 2023-05-01T12:41:52.739Z 08DB49979AAF0242]
```

Comment: Looked at a working project of mine versus yours and the only difference is that I had `SecureSocketOptions.Auto`. Not sure that'll be the key. Otherwise just double check your config is coming through correctly for username and password.

Comment: Thanks @Topher but that still resulted in the same error.

Comment: 1. Does your password use non-ASCII characters? 2. How are you sending mail in your powershell script? System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient? 3. Have you gotten a protocol log (see MailKit's FAQ on how to get one) to see which authentication mechanism is being used? Is it NTLM? 4. What version of MailKit are you using?

Comment: Hi @jstedfast thanks for this! Didn't realize how much context/details I didn't include. Will work on getting these pieces and update post.

Comment: Thanks @jstedfast, updated question with more details/context. Hope that helps somewhat.

Comment: I think Office365 recently disabled LOGIN and now requires you to use XOAUTH2.